# Using a "using" expression to define a type brings up loads of random errors

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am making an eventmanager for a game, but when I try to use the "using" expression to define some types, I get 15 random errors which don't make any sense and has nothing to do with the using expression.

Here is the code WITH the using expressions:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>

using Events = std::vector<std::pair<EventType, EventInfo>>;
using Bindings = std::unordered_map<std::string, Binding*>;
using Callbacks = std::unordered_map<std::string,
    std::function<void(EventDetails*)>>;

class EventManager
{
};

struct Binding {
    Binding(const std::string& l_name)
        : m_name(l_name), m_details(l_name), c(0) {}

    void BindEvent(EventType l_type, EventInfo l_info = EventInfo())
    {
        m_events.emplace_back(l_type, l_info);
    }

    Events m_events;
    std::string m_name;
    int c; // Count of events that are "happening".
    EventDetails m_details;
};

struct EventDetails {
    EventDetails(const std::string& l_bindName)
        : m_name(l_bindName)
    {
        Clear();
    }

    std::string m_name;
    sf::Vector2i m_size;
    sf::Uint32 m_textEntered;
    sf::Vector2i m_mouse;

    int m_mouseWheelDelta;
    int m_keyCode; // Single key code.

    void Clear() {
        m_size = sf::Vector2i(0, 0);
        m_textEntered = 0;
        m_mouse = sf::Vector2i(0, 0);
        m_mouseWheelDelta = 0;
        m_keyCode = -1;
    }
};

struct EventInfo {
    EventInfo() { m_code = 0; }
    EventInfo(int l_event) { m_code = l_event; }
    union {
        int m_code;
    };
};

enum class EventType {
    KeyDown = sf::Event::KeyPressed,
    KeyUp = sf::Event::KeyReleased,
    MButtonDown = sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed,
    MButtonUp = sf::Event::MouseButtonReleased,
    MouseWheel = sf::Event::MouseWheelMoved,
    WindowResized = sf::Event::Resized,
    GainedFocus = sf::Event::GainedFocus,
    LostFocus = sf::Event::LostFocus,
    MouseEntered = sf::Event::MouseEntered,
    MouseLeft = sf::Event::MouseLeft,
    Closed = sf::Event::Closed,
    TextEntered = sf::Event::TextEntered,
    Keyboard = sf::Event::Count + 1, Mouse, Joystick
};
```

Gives errors which don't make any sense:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2065   'EventType': undeclared identifier  SFML-EventManager   C:\Users\wout\source\repos\SFML-EventManager\SFML-EventManager\EventManager.h   5   

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2065   'EventInfo': undeclared identifier  SFML-EventManager   C:\Users\wout\source\repos\SFML-EventManager\SFML-EventManager\EventManager.h   5   

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2923   'std::pair': 'EventType' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty1' SFML-EventManager   C:\Users\wout\source\repos\SFML-EventManager\SFML-EventManager\EventManager.h   5   

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2923   'std::pair': 'EventInfo' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty2' SFML-EventManager   C:\Users\wout\source\repos\SFML-EventManager\SFML-EventManager\EventManager.h   5   

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C3203   'pair': unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter '_Ty', expected a real type    SFML-EventManager   C:\Users\wout\source\repos\SFML-EventManager\SFML-EventManager\EventManager.h   5   

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2065   'Binding': undeclared identifier    SFML-EventManager   C:\Users\wout\source\repos\SFML-EventManager\SFML-EventManager\EventManager.h   6   

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2059   syntax error: '>'   SFML-EventManager   C:\Users\wout\source\repos\SFML-EventManager\SFML-EventManager\EventManager.h   6   

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'   SFML-EventManager   C:\Users\wout\source\repos\SFML-EventManager\SFML-EventManager\EventManager.h   8   

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    SFML-EventManager   C:\Users\wout\source\repos\SFML-EventManager\SFML-EventManager\EventManager.h   26
```

And lots of other random errors...

But when I make this change:

```
//using Events = std::vector<std::pair<EventType, EventInfo>>;
//using Bindings = std::unordered_map<std::string, Binding*>;
//using Callbacks = std::unordered_map<std::string,
//  std::function<void(EventDetails*)>>;
```

I get these errors because the types don't exist (this is normal):

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "Events" is undefined    SFML-EventManager   C:\Users\wout\source\repos\SFML-EventManager\SFML-EventManager\EventManager.h   23  

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'EventType'    SFML-EventManager   C:\Users\wout\source\repos\SFML-EventManager\SFML-EventManager\EventManager.h   18  

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C3646   'm_events': unknown override specifier  SFML-EventManager   C:\Users\wout\source\repos\SFML-EventManager\SFML-EventManager\EventManager.h   23  

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    SFML-EventManager   C:\Users\wout\source\repos\SFML-EventManager\SFML-EventManager\EventManager.h   23  

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C3646   'm_details': unknown override specifier SFML-EventManager   C:\Users\wout\source\repos\SFML-EventManager\SFML-EventManager\EventManager.h   26  

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    SFML-EventManager   C:\Users\wout\source\repos\SFML-EventManager\SFML-EventManager\EventManager.h   26  

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2614   'Binding': illegal member initialization: 'm_details' is not a base or member   SFML-EventManager   C:\Users\wout\source\repos\SFML-EventManager\SFML-EventManager\EventManager.h   16  

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2065   'm_events': undeclared identifier   SFML-EventManager   C:\Users\wout\source\repos\SFML-EventManager\SFML-EventManager\EventManager.h   20  

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2065   'l_type': undeclared identifier SFML-EventManager   C:\Users\wout\source\repos\SFML-EventManager\SFML-EventManager\EventManager.h   20  

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2065   'l_info': undeclared identifier SFML-EventManager   C:\Users\wout\source\repos\SFML-EventManager\SFML-EventManager\EventManager.h   20
```

Any insight is appreciated!

Edit:
I placed the using statement under all referenced types, still get the same errors...

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>

class EventManager {
public:
    EventManager();
    ~EventManager();

    bool AddBinding(Binding* l_binding);
    bool RemoveBinding(std::string l_name);

    void SetFocus(const bool& l_focus);

    // Needs to be defined in the header!
    template<class T>
    bool AddCallback(const std::string& l_name,
        void(T::* l_func)(EventDetails*), T* l_instance)
    {
        auto temp = std::bind(l_func, l_instance,
            std::placeholders::_1);
        return m_callbacks.emplace(l_name, temp).second;
    }
    void RemoveCallback(const std::string& l_name) {
        m_callbacks.erase(l_name);
    }

    void HandleEvent(sf::Event& l_event);
    void Update();

    sf::Vector2i GetMousePos(sf::RenderWindow* l_wind = nullptr) {
        return (l_wind ? sf::Mouse::getPosition(*l_wind)
            : sf::Mouse::getPosition());
    }
private:
    void LoadBindings();

    Bindings m_bindings;
    Callbacks m_callbacks;

    bool m_hasFocus;
};

struct Binding {
    Binding(const std::string& l_name)
        : m_name(l_name), m_details(l_name), c(0) {}

    void BindEvent(EventType l_type, EventInfo l_info = EventInfo())
    {
        m_events.emplace_back(l_type, l_info);
    }

    Events m_events;
    std::string m_name;
    int c; // Count of events that are "happening".
    EventDetails m_details;
};

struct EventDetails {
    EventDetails(const std::string& l_bindName)
        : m_name(l_bindName)
    {
        Clear();
    }

    std::string m_name;
    sf::Vector2i m_size;
    sf::Uint32 m_textEntered;
    sf::Vector2i m_mouse;

    int m_mouseWheelDelta;
    int m_keyCode; // Single key code.

    void Clear() {
        m_size = sf::Vector2i(0, 0);
        m_textEntered = 0;
        m_mouse = sf::Vector2i(0, 0);
        m_mouseWheelDelta = 0;
        m_keyCode = -1;
    }
};

struct EventInfo {
    EventInfo() { m_code = 0; }
    EventInfo(int l_event) { m_code = l_event; }
    union {
        int m_code;
    };
};

enum class EventType {
    KeyDown = sf::Event::KeyPressed,
    KeyUp = sf::Event::KeyReleased,
    MButtonDown = sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed,
    MButtonUp = sf::Event::MouseButtonReleased,
    MouseWheel = sf::Event::MouseWheelMoved,
    WindowResized = sf::Event::Resized,
    GainedFocus = sf::Event::GainedFocus,
    LostFocus = sf::Event::LostFocus,
    MouseEntered = sf::Event::MouseEntered,
    MouseLeft = sf::Event::MouseLeft,
    Closed = sf::Event::Closed,
    TextEntered = sf::Event::TextEntered,
    Keyboard = sf::Event::Count + 1, Mouse, Joystick
};

using Events = std::vector<std::pair<EventType, EventInfo>>;
using Bindings = std::unordered_map<std::string, Binding*>;
using Callbacks = std::unordered_map<std::string,
    std::function<void(EventDetails*)>>;
```

Comment: Smells like it could be a circular `#include`. Are `EventType`, `EventInfo`, etc, declared in a header file that includes the one you've shown? Try forward declaring them instead.

Comment: ...or, have you included any header at all with those declarations?

Comment: All types I used are in the code as enums or structs and this file doesn't get included anywhere except the .cpp file which is empty....

Comment: According to [the SFML `EventType` reference](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Event.php#af41fa9ed45c02449030699f671331d4a) it's defined in [`Event.hpp`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/Event_8hpp_source.php). Which you don't include.

Comment: Looks like you momentarily forgot about the `sf` namespace. Have you tried replacing e.g. `EventType` with `sf::EventType`?

Comment: EventType is my custom struct, it is defined in the header file,

Answer (score 1):

The error is about the missing declarations. The code below would mimic the error you get.

```
// error: 'A' does not name a type    
using B = A;

class A{
    A() { }
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

You just have to declare your types before referring them on the right side of the `using` declarations.

```
// Compiles successfully
class A{
    A() { }
};

using B = A;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I did it, but I got the same errors. Please watch the edit.